# Screen Record Parallax elements on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, video-capture, screen-recording

I'm trying to screen record the following website for use in our portfolio:

http://independentsweek.co.uk

The website contains quite a few parallax elements and I'm using a JavaScript bookmarklet to smooth scroll through the page. The issue is, because the bookmarklet uses a css transforms to scroll through the page, the parallax elements don't parallax.

Is there a known method, which I've failed to stumble across, which both smooth scrolls a page whilst still keeping the parallax items parallaxing?

I plan on using QuickTime to record my screen, as it is native macOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a good old screen video capture? And you can scroll manually

Comment: @JeremyThille human scrolling is janky as hell! We want the scrolling to be smooth otherwise it kind of defeats the point of showcasing it.

Comment: Maybe you can use a little smooth scrolling code snippet : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: @JeremyThille yeah, I have a bookmarklet doing that. When I run the smooth scrolling JS, the parallax items don't parallax because it's not actually scrolling the page, it's using a CSS transform.

Comment: So, use a jQuery snippet that will actually scroll the page down?

Comment: @JeremyThille Never thought of that! Just used a jQuery scrollTop to scroll and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a Bookmarklet that injected JS to run a CSS Transformation, I used jQuery's scrollTop() function, scrolling to the ID of my footer.

The code I'm currently using is:

```
javascript:jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#mastfoot").offset().top},22000);
```

Hope somebody finds this helpful!